# How can I analyze online SQL Server database pressure?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, analysis

I want to analyze pressure on my SQL Server. so I can find which table will be query more than the others and cache data for that.
So how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this article which explains using DMV's (Dynamic Management Views) to retrieve the top n most expensive SQL queries by logical reads, writes or CPU time:

[SQL SERVER – Find Most Expensive Queries Using DMV](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/05/14/sql-server-find-most-expensive-queries-using-dmv/)

In case the link becomes unavailable I have included the query below:

```
SELECT TOP 10 SUBSTRING(qt.TEXT, (qs.statement_start_offset/2)+1,
((CASE qs.statement_end_offset
WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(qt.TEXT)
ELSE qs.statement_end_offset
END - qs.statement_start_offset)/2)+1),
qs.execution_count,
qs.total_logical_reads, qs.last_logical_reads,
qs.total_logical_writes, qs.last_logical_writes,
qs.total_worker_time,
qs.last_worker_time,
qs.total_elapsed_time/1000000 total_elapsed_time_in_S,
qs.last_elapsed_time/1000000 last_elapsed_time_in_S,
qs.last_execution_time,
qp.query_plan
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) qt
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) qp
ORDER BY qs.total_logical_reads DESC -- logical reads
-- ORDER BY qs.total_logical_writes DESC -- logical writes
-- ORDER BY qs.total_worker_time DESC -- CPU time
```

Comment: As I found it generate report for online queries. how can I get report for specific time (for example last week or last month)?

Comment: Unfortunately the sys.dm_exec_query_stats view only provides the overall stats of each distinct query ran. So it only stores the first/last time it was executed. As far as I know SQL does not log each individual query executed only the stats on distinct query executions. If you need an overview of all queries executed over a short period take a look at SQL Profiler [Introducing SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx)